# No sound from Audient Evo-4 audio interface

Tags: sound

I;m new around here and trying to get sound to come through my audio interface into my speakers. Would like to use Bitwig to make some music. Just installed Ubuntu Studio Jellyfish and the install seemed to go well.  I can select the internal desktop speaker and sound comes out. I can select the speakers in my monitor and sound comes out. If I test sound in the evo-4 nothing comes out, but the dial lights up indicating it's getting signal. Bitwig in Windows 10 with this evo4 audio interface works fine. This is a mystery..any help appreciated. I would love to bail on Windows. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it needs a driver. Did you check with the maker and look on their web site to see if it works with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question so maybe this will help someone else.

I just saw that there is a new version of Ubuntu Studio just out of beta.  vs 22.10. They said it uses something called Pipewire for audio now.  Since I didnt have much invested in the earlier version I thought lets give this one a try and maybe it will fix this audio issue..It did!  My audio interface is working just fine now

The earlier version thought my evo4 is a surround device and it is not.  It's analog stereo.  22.10 correctly sees it and I am getting pristine audio now. Havent yet tried it in a daw but think it will be fine. Hope this helps